# Mapbox GL this.map.on('load') event works locally but not when i deploy to vercel

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, mapbox-gl-js, vercel

I am making an interactive map with mapbox and nuxt that sets the visibility of certain layers when the map loads. I also set up a queryRenderedFeatures function using `this.map.on('mousemove')`, like this:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    map: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    layerIds: ['Zip Code', 'Network'],
    zone: 'Zip Code'
  }),

  mounted () {
    this.map.on('load', () => { this.map.setLayoutProperty(this.layerIds[0], 'visibility', 'visible') })
    this.map.on('load', () => { this.map.setLayoutProperty(this.layerIds[1], 'visibility', 'none') })
    this.map.on('mousemove', (e) => {
      if( this.zone == 'Zip Code'){
        const features = this.map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point)
...
```

Right now this is all being called in the mounted hook of a child of my map component and everything works as it should when i deploy to a local server. However, when I deploy to vercel, the map displays both layers on load, instead of just the first one, and returns a console error:

```
TypeError: this.map.on is not a function
    at c.mounted (98d0728.js:1)
    at ii (b366f77.js:2)
    at vn (b366f77.js:2)
    at Object.insert (b366f77.js:2)
    at $ (b366f77.js:2)
    at zn.__patch__ (b366f77.js:2)
    at zn.t._update (b366f77.js:2)
    at zn.o (b366f77.js:2)
    at Tn.get (b366f77.js:2)
    at new Tn (b366f77.js:2)
ai @ b366f77.js:2
manifest.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I have found some threads that suggest mapbox is not compatible with server side rendering but I'm not confident thats the issue or even true at this point. either way, my attempts to add the `target: 'static'` line to my nuxt.config.js and refactor the mapbox gl import as a const in mounted have been unsuccessful so far. Anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Alright, toggling between `'static'` and `'server'` for your `target` is not a thing to do. You need to decide which one you do need and stick with it. Vercel is only able to serve static files like a CDN aka only `target: 'static'`. If you want to keep the rendering as server, host it on Heroku or something alike. Also, to double-check: does it work locally when you build your app?

Comment: @kissu thank you for this answer but I am still confused because Nuxt [link](https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/) makes "going full static" seem very simple: 
_"Upgrade nuxt to 2.14.0,
Set target: 'static' in your nuxt.config.js,
Run nuxt generate,
That's it ✨"_

Additionally, Vercel was billed by both the Nuxt team and a Vercel sales rep as suitable for ssr. Maybe is this a mapbox problem? their documentation is less clear on this.

to answer your last question, no, npm run build, then start produces the same result as deploying to vercel.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove these errors by consolidating my nested UI component and its parent mapbox component, and rendering the app according to Nuxt's "full static" guide. I'm sure there are many different ways to solve this, some of which might allow me to retain server side rendering, and I would like to explore others like the use of Nuxt client side plugins for this purpose, but this solution works for me because server side rendering was a little overkill here anyway and static rendering is faster too.

Comment: If you want to go static, Vercel is a good way solution indeed. Just don't pick static because it works better than server in your case but for a specific reason.

Comment: @kissu totally get it, thanks. just kind of doing triage with the skills I have right now too